# Retrieve an Integer part from a String

Tags: java, string, int

I have to use an int value "nid" to work on. But this int value should be an combination of int "did" and String "a"!

```
int did = 123456;
String a = "_b";
int nid = Integer.parseInt((did+a).toString());
```

But for this code i get the error message

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123456_b"
```

Is there any way, to convert a combination of int and string to int?

Comment: What int value are you looking for from "123456_b"?  `b` is not a number.

Comment: You can't convert `String` to `int`. `nid` should be `String`.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/286538). Can you explain the context of your question? What is the `nid`, why does it have to be integer, where do you intend to use it?

Comment: "nid" is used in an XML schema and it should give an reference to some other attributes. So the schema definition itself says, that "nid" must be an int, so there is no chance to change to String. And with the combination of "did" and "a" there should be a specific reference given,which is needed.

Comment: what do you want to accomplish? purpose of code is not clear

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way, to convert a combination of int and string to int?

Only if the string is a numeric value.
It is not your case.
`Integer.parseInt(String)` waits for a String parameter that is a parsable integer.
But you could never use the `"_b"` `String` as a valid part of an integer value.

However, you can store the computation as a String :

```
int did = 123456;
String a = "_b";
String nid = did + a;
```

Comment: Assume the ascii digits are first in the string. use charAt() in a loop to find the last such character. Use substring() to extract these characters. Use Integer.parseInt() to get the integer.

Comment: @Marichyasana  It is right but it assumes that we can discard some parts of the original String in the final computation. The question is not very clear about it. I would have not answered to.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a String "123456_b", and you want to retrieve a numeric part of it. Am I right?

In this case, you can use regex - "(d+)[_a-zA-Z]". Let's assume that numeric part ends with underscore character ( _ ). That's why I put it into the regex. I used a group (d+) to catch a numeric part.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "1234567_abcde";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)[_]?[a-zA-Z]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Did not find a numeric part.");
            return;
        }

        String numericGroup = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(numericGroup);
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numericGroup);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the non numeric characters first and then try parsing it

```
String str = did+a;
str = str.replaceAll("/[^0-9]/g", "");
int nid = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want. 
The error is normal, *b* is not a number and you can't declare *nid* as int.

Maybe you want just to concatenate *a* with *did* ?

On this case, *nid* must be a String, not a int.